# SPST Power Switch with LED for Guitar Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, switches, dpdt

I would like to have a power switch for the solid state guitar amp I am building, but I would like an LED indicator to know when it is on. I know how to do this using a dpdt on-off, but would it be possible to use an spst and still have the LED?

Comment: depends on what you are switching. ... is it actual power? or is it some sort of a mute switch?

Comment: Power, sorry. Not a standby.

Comment: Yes. Just run the LED from the power. Power present means LED is on. And conversely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Put the LED in parallel with your amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvxnfH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>